# Decode days of the week format

Tags: php

I'm working with an existing scheduling system that stores a single numerical value for the days of a week that an appointment recurs.

The mapping is as follow:

```
Monday = 64
Tuesday = 32
Wednesday = 16
Thursday = 8
Friday = 4
Saturday = 2
Sunday = 1
```

So for example if the value stored for an appointment is "108" that means the appointment recurs on Monday, Tuesday, Thursday and Friday (64+32+8+4).

Is there a straightforward way I can decode the numerical value (108) in PHP to get the list of days?

**Update: This value is a bitwise operator. Can PHP easily decode this?**

Comment: PHP has the & operator, doesn't it?

Comment: Luckily none of the numbers add up to each other, so you can just start subtracting from largest to smallest while checking for 0.

Comment: Not helpful but: this has to be the smartest implementation of this ever. And by smartest I mean worst

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: see [bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
$week = [
    'Monday' => 64, // 1000000 in binary
    'Tuesday' => 32, // 0100000 in binary
    'Wednesday' => 16, // 0010000 ...etc
    'Thursday' => 8,
    'Friday' => 4,
    'Saturday' => 2,
    'Sunday' => 1,
];

$saved_days = 108; // 1101100 in binary

$days = [];
foreach ($week as $day => $bit_value) {
    if ($saved_days & $bit_value) {
        $days[] = $day;
    }
}

var_dump($days);
```

The result:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Monday"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Tuesday"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "Thursday"
  [3]=>
  string(6) "Friday"
}
```

The idea behind this way is to make a bitmap to mark the days, so 108 = 64+32+8+4 is in binary 1101100, each bit marks a day (Monday to Sunday).